# adding parallell to a stream causes NullPointerException

Tags: parallel-processing, java-stream

I'm trying to get my head around Java streams. It was my understanding that they provide an easy way to parallellize behaviour, and that also not all operations benefit from parallellization, but that you always have the option to do it by just slapping .parallell() on to an existing stream. This might make the stream go slower in some cases, or return the elements in a different order at the end etc, but you always have the option to parallellize a stream. That's why I got confused when I changed this method:

```
public static List<Integer> primeSequence() {
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    IntStream.range(1, 10)
            .filter(x -> isPrime(x))
            .forEach(list::add);
    return list;
}
//returns {2,3,5,7}
```

to this:

```
public static List<Integer> primeSequence() {
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    IntStream.range(1, 10).parallel()
            .filter(x -> isPrime(x))
            .forEach(list::add);
    return list;
}
//throws NullPointerException();
```

I thought all streams were serial unless otherwise stated and parallel() just made then execute in parallel. What am I missing here? Why does it throw an Exception?

Comment: A `LinkedList` is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one significant issue with your initial `primeSequence` method implementation - you mix stream iteration with outer list modification. You should avoid using streams that way, otherwise you will face a lot of problems. Like the one you have described. If you take a look at how `add(E element)` method is implemented you will see something like this:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    this.linkLast(e);
    return true;
}

void linkLast(E e) {
    LinkedList.Node<E> l = this.last;
    LinkedList.Node<E> newNode = new LinkedList.Node(l, e, (LinkedList.Node)null);
    this.last = newNode;
    if (l == null) {
        this.first = newNode;
    } else {
        l.next = newNode;
    }

    ++this.size;
    ++this.modCount;
}
```

If you use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead of a `LinkedList` in your example, there will be no `NullPointerException` thrown - only because `CopyOnWriteArrayList` uses locking for multithread execution synchronization:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();

    boolean var6;
    try {
        Object[] elements = this.getArray();
        int len = elements.length;
        Object[] newElements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, len + 1);
        newElements[len] = e;
        this.setArray(newElements);
        var6 = true;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }

    return var6;
}
```

But it is still not the best way to utilize parallel stream.

#### Correct way to use Stream API

Consider following modification to your code:

```
public static List<Integer> primeSequence() {
    return IntStream.range(1, 10)
        .parallel()
        .filter(x -> isPrime(x))
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Instead of modifying some outer list (of any kind) we are collecting the result and return a final list. You can transform any list to a stream using `.stream()` method and you don't have to worry about initial list - all operation you will apply to that list won't modify the input and the result will be a copy of the input list.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Got it. Does the toList() return a read only list so that Id have to add the elements of it to a regular list if I want an ArrayList or LinkedList?

Comment: @user1661303 `Collectors.toList()` returns `ArrayList`, but If you want `LinkedList` instead you can use following `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))` to specify what exact collection type you expect in return.